# Matlab ldl(B,v) function to C

Tags: c, matlab, matrix-factorization

I am working on translating Matlab code to C code, but I encountered this function for matrix factorization.

```
    [L,D,pm] = ldl(B,'vector');
```

where `B`, is the matrix, `L` is the lower triangle and `D` is the upper, while `pm` is a permutation. I found the C implementation for factorization but without the permutation.

Could you please tell where to find it?

Comment: Just use this form of the function `[L,D] = ldl(A)`. Look here for more info: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ldl.html

Comment: I need to convert it to C code, the code I am translating is uses this format and using the pm matrix also

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-perform-lu-decomposition-any-matrix/

Comment: This is off topic: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*. Please rephrase by describing what behaviour you're missing, what you might have tried etc.